# Post to facebook wall that user installed app

Tags: iphone, facebook

Sometimes when an app utilizing Facebook is installed, a post saying "User has installed the MyAppName for iPhone App" is posted to the user's wall. How is this achieved please?

Comment: you want to publish on user wall that he has joined your application when he authnticates your application?

Answer (score 2):

Use the javascript method of publish stream.

```
 FB.ui({
    method: 'stream.publish',
    message:'hello',
    attachment: {
      name: title,

      caption: "I'm running!",
      media: [{
        type: 'image',
        href: 'http://www.yoursite.com/',
        src: 'http://www.yoursite.com/images/working.jpeg'
      }]
    },
    action_links: [{
      text: 'Get your percentage',
      href: 'http://www.yoursite/'
    }],
    user_message_prompt: 'Tell your friends about your application:'
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, but for this to work, one would need to ask for the feed permission at authentication as well, which is something I would like to avoid.

Comment: you want that stream is published automatically without asking user?

Comment: Yes Awais, I will love to hear the way to do that without permission